# Limitations of C# Action lambda code blocks

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, lambda

C# .NET 3.5.  I'm trying to understand the intrinsic limitation of the C# Action object.  Within the lamda (are those, in fact, lamdas?), we can perform assignments, call functions, even execute a ternary operation, but we can't execute a multi-statement operation.

Is this because the single-statement execution is just syntactic sugar for wrapping it in a delegate?  Why does the first example below not work?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int m_Count = 0;

    public void Test()
    {
        int value = 0;

        // Does not work, throws compile error
        Action action = () => { if(m_Count < 10) m_Count++; value = m_Count; }

        // Works
        Action action2 = () => value = delegate(){ 
            if(m_Count < 10) 
                m_Count++; 

            return m_Count;
        };

        // Works
        Action action3 = () => value = m_Count;

        // Works
        Action action4 = () => value = m_Count < 10 ? m_Count++ : 0;

        // Works
        Action action5 = () => value = Increment();
    }

    public int Increment()
    {
        if (m_Count < 10)
            m_Count++;

        return m_Count;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Grr, sorry for the noise.  Originally, I had

```
Action action = () => if(m_Count < 10) m_Count++; value = m_Count;
```

Which threw a compile error, but then right before the post I thought I'd try wrapping it in braces

```
Action action = () => { if(m_Count < 10) m_Count++; value = m_Count; }
```

Which also threw a compile error, so I jumped to conclusions that it was the same problem.  It works, though, if I toss in a semi-colon after the braces

```
Action action = () => { if(m_Count < 10) m_Count++; value = m_Count; };
```

Sorry for the noise!

EDIT 2: Thanks cfeduke, you posted that at the same time as my edit above - went ahead and marked as answer.

Comment: Can't immediately see what's wrong - what compile error did you get?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing a semi-colon, it compiles:

```
 Action action = () => { if (m_Count < 10) m_Count++; value = m_Count; };
```

When you say `type name = statement;` you need a semicolon even if you use braces for a code block.

Comment: I suppose the following should also work:? `Action<int> action = (thrshld) => { if (m_Count < thrshld) m_Count++; value = m_Count; };`

Answer (score 5):

cfeduke has posted the solution to getting your code to compile.

Note that you can't convert statement-block lambda expressions into expression trees, even though you can convert them into delegates. There are [other limitations](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=68) on what you can convert into expression trees.

Going back to delegates, there are *some* limitations there - you can't write an iterator block within a lambda expression, for example. (I've wanted to do that before now - it gets weird when you try to get your head round it. You can't do it though.) For the most part, you can do almost anything you can do in a method.